# How to add onItemClickListener in a listview to display the image of that row

Tags: android

I am using a `ListView` in my Android program.

I have some rows and I once a row is clicked, I want to open a new activity. How can I achieve this?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listView1;
Weather weather_data[] =null;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Weather weather_data[] = new Weather[]
    {
        new Weather(R.drawable.a, "Mercedes Benz"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.b, "Xuv 500"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.c, "Audi"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.d, "Benz"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.e, "Ferrari"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.a, "Mercedes Benz"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.b, "Xuv 500"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.c, "Audi"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.d, "Benz"),
        new Weather(R.drawable.e, "Ferrari")
    };

    WeatherAdapter adapter = new WeatherAdapter(this,R.layout.listview_item_row,weather_data);

    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listview_header_row, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);
    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

   listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,long id) 
    {

         //int Integer = ((ImageView)v).getId();
        // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
        Weather wea=(Weather) weather_data[position];
        String product=wea.title;
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
         // sending data to new activity
         intent.putExtra("index", product);
         startActivity(intent);
        }
})
```

Comment: What is the problem you are facing with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the following code in your `onItemClick()` method.

```
if(position == ROW_NO_1){
    Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_CONTEXT,FirstActivity.class);
     // sending data to new activity
     intent.putExtra("index", VALUE_OF_THIS_ROW_ITEM);
     startActivity(intent);
} else if(position == ROW_NO_2){
    Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_CONTEXT,SecondActivity.class);
     // sending data to new activity
     intent.putExtra("index", VALUE_OF_THIS_ROW_ITEM);
     startActivity(intent);
} else if(position == ROW_NO_3){
    Intent intent = new Intent(YOUR_CONTEXT,ThirdActivity.class);
     // sending data to new activity
     intent.putExtra("index", VALUE_OF_THIS_ROW_ITEM);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Note:** its just a hint. You can formulate your code according to your need.

By the way what problem are you currently facing?